# How to fix Aggregation in Group By, missing aggregation values

Tags: sql-server, group-by, grouping, aggregation

I have a table of sales info, and am interested in Grouping by customer, and returning the sum, count, max of a  few columns.  Any ideas please.

I checked all the Select columns are included in the Group By statement, a detail is returned not the Groupings and aggregate values.
I tried some explicit naming but that didn't help.

```
SELECT
    customerID AS CUST,
    COUNT([InvoiceID]) AS Count_Invoice,
    SUM([Income]) AS Total_Income,
    SUM([inc2015]) AS Tot_2015_Income,
    SUM([inc2016]) AS Tot_2016_Income,
    MAX([prodA]) AS prod_A,
FROM [table_a] 
GROUP BY
    customerID, InvoiceID,Income,inc2015, inc2016, prodA
```

There are multiple rows of CUST, i.e. there should be one row for CUST 1, 2 etc.... it should say this...

```
    ---------------------------------------------
    CUST    Count_Invoice   Total_Income    Tot_2015_Income Tot_2016_Income prod_A

       1    2   600 300 300 2


    BUT IT IS RETURNING THIS
    ======================================
    CUST    Count_Invoice   Total_Income    Tot_2015_Income Tot_2016_Income prod_A

       1    1   300 300 0   1

       1    1   300 0   300 1

       2    1   300 0   300 1

       2    1   500 0   500 0

       3    2   800 0   800 0

       3    1   300 0   300 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to `group by` other columns, since they are already aggregating by `count`, `min`, `max` or `sum`.

So you may try this

```
SELECT customerID as CUST
,count([InvoiceID]) as Count_Invoice
 ,sum([Income]) as Total_Income
,sum([inc2015]) as Tot_2015_Income
 ,sum([inc2016]) as Tot_2016_Income
,max([prodA])  as prod_A    --- here you are taking Max but in output it seems like sum
 FROM [table_a] 
 Group By customerID
```

Note: For column `prod_A` you are using `max` which gives `1` but in result it is showing `2` which is actually `sum` or `count`. Please check.

for more info you may find this link of [Group by](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Answer (score 0):

From the description of your expected output, you should be aggregating by customer alone:

```
SELECT
    customerID A CUST,
    COUNT([InvoiceID]) AS Count_Invoice,
    SUM([Income]) AS Total_Income,
    SUM([inc2015]) AS Tot_2015_Income,
    SUM([inc2016]) AS Tot_2016_Income,
    MAX([prodA]) AS prod_A
FROM [table_a] 
GROUP BY  
    customerID;
```

Comment: Thank you, I misunderstood about the need to mirror groupby/select items